# how to write test class for delete batch?

Tags: apex, batch

Here is the code

```
global class DeleteRjectedQuote implements Database.Batchable{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select id,Status from Case where Status='Escalated']);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,list lstcase){

        if(!lstcase.isEmpty()){
            delete lstcase;
        } 
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ }

}
```

test class::
i have gone through trailhead but I am getting 0 codecoverage. How can we increase code coverage::

```
@isTest
public class TestDeleteRjectedQuote {
    @isTest static void testDeleteRjectedQuotemethod(){
        Test.startTest();
        Case qt = new Case();
        qt.status = 'escalated';
        insert qt;   
        DeleteRjectedQuote drq = new DeleteRjectedQuote();
        database.executeBatch(drq);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, why you need batch class for deleting the cases.

Comment: I am doing it as practice. Anyone have idea about it?

Comment: [Getting Started with Apex Unit Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro)

Comment: i have gone through trailhead but I am getting 0 codecoverage. How can we increase code coverage::

Comment: [Using Batch Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch) has a section on coverage also.

Comment: Did you write a test class? If so, **[edit]** it into your Original Post so we can tell that you have already made an attempt.

Comment: hi adrian ,    I have added test class with code.

Comment: You need the test to actually run the batch. All it is doing now is creating a case.

Comment: I think that your problem is when you are creating the case. Status = 'escalated' and in the query you put 'Escalated'

Comment: @Torsen No, `WHERE` clauses filter in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: @AdrianLarson thx I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, you have not completed the [Using Batch Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch) module on Trailhead, because the intro page lays out how to test the batch and your test looks nothing like their example. Here is the basic structure they use:

```
@IsTest
class MyBatchTests
{
    @TestSetup
    static void setup()
    {
        // create your data
    }

    static testMethod void testMyBatch()
    {
        Test.startTest();
            MyBatch batch = new MyBatch();
            Database.executeBatch(batch);
        Test.stopTest();

        system.assert(someCondition, '<message>');
    }
}
```

The key is that you need to instantiate an instance of your batch and pass it to the **`Database.executeBatch`** method. Make liberal use of assertions as well. See also: **[How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)**

Comment: still not getting good coverege

Comment: Is your test passing? If your test encounters an exception it will fail. You never get coverage from a failing test...

Comment: I am getting below exception : System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 2016-01-01 00:00:00, Actual: 2025-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: So obviously your assertion needs to be fixed...

Comment: Or the alternative is that your assertion is correct, and your *code* needs to be fixed. In which case, the Unit Test did exactly what it was supposed to do in failing.